# Is there a way to fix scanf detecting enter without using fgets (scanf detects enter causing dowhile to run twice)

Tags: c

I was experiencing the same issue as someone here, where the enter key for scanf gets detected, causing the while loop to loop 2 times.

The easy fix was to add a space in front of %c for scanf, or just use fgets.
However in my code, both of them dont work.

So I'm doing a hangman game where the letters in the string entered by player 1 will be masked and to do so, I used a for loop such that for every letter in the player 1 input, player1Mask will concatenate an underscore, thereby "masking" or hiding the letter.

```
if player 1 inputs "cats", a for loop will loop through player 1's input and replace player1Word Mask with a hyphen. So player1WordMask is "----"
```

When player 2 enters a letter using a scanf, it will do a for loop such that for every letter in player1Input, if the letter of player 2 is the same as that letter, it will replace that the "mask" in playerMask, which is a hyphen, with the letter of player2Input.

```
if player 2 enters 'a', playerMask will become '-a--'.
```

All these will be done in a do while loop that checks if player 2 ran out of guesses, or player 2 guessed the word.

My issue comes with scanf, where it will detect the enter key which cause a new line, running the loop twice. I can't put a space in front of the %c in player 2 input as it will break the checking functions between mask and player1, making the game run endlessly.

fgets will cause the entire game to run without inputting anything, ending the program. So is there a way to prevent scanf from making the do while run twice without using fgets?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define WORDLIMIT 12
#define NUMBER_OF_GUESSES 7

char player1Word[WORDLIMIT];
char player1WordMask[WORDLIMIT];

char player2Input;
int player2GuessCount=7;

int specialCharFlag = 0;
int isWordAllowed = 0;
int guessCorrectly = 0;
int gameWon = 1;

int main(void)
{

    do //check if player 1 word is valid
    {
        // prompt and get the word
        printf("Player 1, enter a word of no more than %d letters:\n", WORDLIMIT);
        fgets(player1Word,WORDLIMIT,stdin);

        // Player 1 enters a word with upper case letters, the program should change them to lower case.
        for(int i = 0; i<strlen(player1Word); i++)
        {
            player1Word[i] = tolower(player1Word[i]);
        }

        //special character flag
        specialCharFlag = 0;

        if (strlen(player1Word) > 12)
        {
            printf("Enter a word of no more than %d letters:\n", WORDLIMIT);
            specialCharFlag = 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(player1Word); i++)
        {
            //If Player 1 enters a word with punctuation marks or digits, he or she should be asked to enter another word.
            if (player1Word[i] == '!' || player1Word[i] == '@' ||
                    player1Word[i] == '#' || player1Word[i] == '$' ||
                    player1Word[i] == '%' || player1Word[i] == '^' ||
                    player1Word[i] == '&' || player1Word[i] == '*' ||
                    player1Word[i] == '(' || player1Word[i] == ')' ||
                    player1Word[i] == '-' || player1Word[i] == '{' ||
                    player1Word[i] == '}' || player1Word[i] == '[' ||
                    player1Word[i] == ']' || player1Word[i] == ':' ||
                    player1Word[i] == ';' || player1Word[i] == '"' ||
                    player1Word[i] == '\'' || player1Word[i] == '<' ||
                    player1Word[i] == '>' || player1Word[i] == '.' ||
                    player1Word[i] == '/' || player1Word[i] == '?' ||
                    player1Word[i] == '~' || player1Word[i] == '`' ||
                    player1Word[i] == '_')
            {
                printf("Sorry, the word must contain only English letters.\n");
                specialCharFlag = 1;
            }
        }

        if (specialCharFlag == 1)
        {
            isWordAllowed = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            isWordAllowed = 1;
        }

    }
    while (isWordAllowed == 0);

    //At the beginning of each round, the program will output a row of characters containing one underscore for every letter in the word to be guessed.
    for(int i = 0; i<strlen(player1Word)-1; i++)
    {
        player1WordMask[i] = '_';
    }

    do
    {
        // Player 2 (who again has not been watching Player 1) will be asked to guess one letter at a time.
        printf("Player 2 has so far guessed: %s\n",player1WordMask);
        printf("Player 2, you have %d guesses remaining. Enter your next guess:\n",player2GuessCount);
        scanf("%c",&player2Input);

        player2Input = tolower(player2Input);

        guessCorrectly = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(player1Word); i++)
        {
            //If Player 2 has previously guessed a letter that is in the word, the underscore will be replaced by that letter.
            if (player1Word[i] == player2Input)
            {
                player1WordMask[i] = player2Input;
                guessCorrectly = 1;
            }
        }

        if(guessCorrectly == 0)
        {
            player2GuessCount -= 1;
        }

        gameWon = strcmp(player1Word,player1WordMask);
        if(gameWon==0)
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    while(player2GuessCount!=0);

    if(gameWon == 0)
    {
        printf("Player 2 wins.");
    }



}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes the exact input required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The condition `if (strlen(player1Word) > 12)` will always be false, because `fgets` is unable to read more than 11 characters (including the newline character, but not including the terminating null character).

Comment: "both of them dont work." In your code, you did not add the space before `%c`. No wonder it doesn't work if you don't do it.

Comment: `if (player1Word[i] == '!' ||` That huge condition could be replaced by a single `isalpha()`.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently putting space in front of %c of scanf for player2Input was the correct thing to do.

The problem was player1Word. I shouldn't have used fgets for that, rather `scanf(" %s",&player1Word)`, which solved everything including the masking of the word.